# Append serial number of certificate to dict

Tags: ansible

Imagine this dict:

```yaml
my_dict:
  dev_one:
    crt_path: anywhere.crt
  dev_two:
    crt_path: somewhere.crt
```

I am trying to list the serial number for each cert in the dict, and add that value as a  value to the dict again. So far, I can loop over the items in the list and check the serial number.

```yaml
- community.crypto.x509_certificate_info:
    path: "/tmp/{{ my_dict[item].crt_path }}"
  loop: "{{ my_dict.keys() | list }}"
  register: crt_check

- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}" # item.serial_number for the serial number
  loop: "{{ crt_check.results }}"
```

This is the part where I am stuck. When I check the output of the debug message, there is no 'common denominator' between the key/values of the dict, and e.g. the serial number.
Let's say there are 100 items in the dict executing that task, how would I ensure the correct serial number would be added to the correct dict key?

End result:

```yaml
my_dict:
  dev_one:
    filename: anywhere.crt
    serial: xyz
  dev_two:
    filename: somewhere.crt
    serial: abc
```

Comment: `there is no 'common denominator' between the key/values of the dict, and e.g. the serial number.` <= not even `item.item` which contains the dict key you looped over in the previous task ?

Comment: I see indeed, it is there, `item.item`. But how would I add the serial to the dict then?  I can't 'double loop', right?

Answer (score 1):

Now you understood from my comment the `item.item` containing your previous loop item in each result of your registered var, you have to know that you basically don't modifiy existing variables in ansible: you create new ones.

In your case and just to put you on track, here is how I would try (untested, written on spot).

```yaml
- name: Create my dict adding my serial numbers
  vars:
    current_serial:
      serial: "{{ item.serial_number }}"
    current_key: "{{ {item.item: my_dict[item.item] | combine(current_serial)} }}"
  set_fact:
    my_dict_serialed: >-
      {{
        my_dict_serialed | default({})
        | combine(current_key)
      }}
  loop: "{{ crt_check.results }}"

- debug:
    var: my_dict_serialed
```

Comment: I got it figured it out, thanks. I simply assumed there was/is a way easier/prettier method to do this. As I'm creating and combining lists. And, I'm even using double loop, haha.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I think this can be done way prettier, but here it is:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    key_serial: >-
      {{
        key_serial | default([]) +
        [ {'name': item.item, 'serial': item.serial_number} ]
      }}
  loop: "{{ serial_check.results }}"

- name: check | update the items of the dict to the attribute environment
  set_fact:
    my_dict: "{{ my_dict | combine({item.0.key: my_dict[item.0.key] | combine(item.1)}) }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ my_dict | dict2items }}"
    - "{{ key_serial }}"
  when: item.0.key in item.1.name

- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_dict }}"
```

Gives:

```yaml
my_dict:
  dev_one:
    crt_path: anywhere.crt
    serial: abc
  dev_two:
    crt_path: somewhere.crt
    serial: xyz
```